# What circumstances will messages not be consumed or delay consumed in rocketmq cluster?

Tags: rocketmq

I have more than five hundred topic in one cluster with six nodes, I create the topic like this :

```
./mqadmin updateTopic -c MyCluster -n 192.168.1.100:9876 -r 16 -w 16 -t topic1; 
./mqadmin updateTopic -c MyCluster -n 192.168.1.100:9876 -r 16 -w 16 -t topic500;
```

I can send the message without delay ,but I find sometime that the client can not consume the message because the broker do not have consume client.How to fix this bug?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

do following check

- more than 1 consumer instance started in one machine.
  if so , make every consumer instance client id or client name different
- consumer instances in this `c_fy_core` consumer group sub different topic and tags.
  if so , make sure all consumer instances in one consumer group sub same topic-and-tags